# Replace a string by a file which name equals regex capture group

Tags: sed

I have a file named `foo` where I want to replace the line containing the following regex match:

```
<script.*src="(.*)".*><\/script>
```

With the content of a file which name equals the first capture group in the regex above. For example, I might have the following line in `foo`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bar.js"></script>
```

Which I want to replace with the content from the file `bar.js`.

I want to somehow open the file referenced by the first capture group. This is what I have so far:

```
sed -r "s/<script.*src=\"(.*)\".*><\/script>/$(cat \1) /" foo
```

But I am getting `cat: 1: No such file or directory`.

Even when I try to manually specify the file I want to open I get an Error which I can't understand:

```
sed -r "s/<script.*src=\"(.*)\".*><\/script>/$(cat bar.js)/" test.txt
```

Error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 53: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: `to somehow open the file` What do you mean by "open the file"? You want to replace the line `<script....` with the content of the file? Split problems to parts - first, get what file to open. Then, read the content of the file. Then replace the line with content of the file.

Comment: @KamilCuk Reading the file. Thanks for the clarified problem description, that is exactly what I am trying to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get what file to open:

```
file=$(sed -En 's|.*<script.*src="(.*)".*></script>.*|\1|p' test.txt)
```

Then you can delete the line and read the file in `sed` using `r` command and delete line with `d`.

```
sed -E -e '\|.*<script.*src="(.*)".*></script>.*|{ r '"$file" -e 'd;}' test.txt
```

You can use `e` extension to GNU `sed` and execute a script instead of the part.

```
sed -E 's|<script.*src="(.*)".*></script>|cat \1|e' test.txt
```

You should strongly consider using an XML aware parser, like `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint`, and consider using a real programming language, at least scripting one like `python` or `perl`.